# SQL set status based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, mysqli, informatica

Source Table:

```
ID | TYP | PREF | TRG | RTG | FLG

1 | 6 | 1 | YES | HIGH | 1

2 | 6 | 2 | NO | HIGH | 0

3 | 7 | 1 | YES | LOW | 1

4 | 7 | 2 | YES | NEUTRAL | 0

9 | 7 | 3 | YES | NEUTRAL | 0

4 | 6 | 1 | YES |LOW  | 1

7 | 6 | 2 | YES | HIGH | 0 |

5 | 8 | 1 | NO | NEUTRAL | 1

6 | 8 |2 | NO | LOW | 0
```

If PREF=YES and 
For a particular TYP, where FLAG=1,
if any one TRG is HIGH, then set status as HIGH.
Similarly, any one TRG is NEUTRAL, then set status as NEUTRAL, else LOW. If FLAG=0, then set STATUS=TRG.
If PREF=NO, no STATUS

Expected Target Table:

```
ID | TYP | PREF | TRG | RTG | FLG |STATUS

1 | 6 | 1 | YES | HIGH | 1 | HIGH

2 | 6 | 2 | NO | HIGH | 0 | 

3 | 7 | 1 | YES | LOW | 1 | NEUTRAL

4 | 7 | 2 | YES | NEUTRAL | 0 | NEUTRAL

9 | 7 | 3 | YES | NEUTRAL | 0 | NEUTRAL

4 | 6 | 1 | YES |LOW  | 1 | HIGH

7 | 6 | 2 | YES | HIGH | 0 | HIGH

5 | 8 | 1 | NO | NEUTRAL | 1 | 

6 | 8 |2 | NO | LOW | 0 |
```

How to achieve this?
The main part I'm stuck is to check data for a particular value in TYP column. If any 1 value for TYP is High, then set status as High only where Flah=1 and so on. Example for TYP 7, TRG is Low, Neutral, Neutral. ,So set status as Neutral where flag=1. If flag=0, set as per TRG.

Comment: What have you tried already that did not work?  All you need is some CASE statements in your SELECT query.  Please read it up online.

Comment: You should probably read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: Yes thanks I'm aware of Case. But I'm more stuck up to iterate and check data as per a particular value in TYP column

Answer (score 0):

CASE will do the trick:

```
SELECT
ID , TYP , PREF , TRG , RTG , FLG ,   
CASE WHEN PREF='YES'  AND FLAG=1 AND TRG='HIGH' THEN 'HIGH'
     WHEN PREF='YES'  AND FLAG=1 AND TRG='NEUTRAL' THEN 'NEUTRAL'
     WHEN FLAG=0 THEN 'TRG'
     ELSE 'LOW
END CASE as STATUS
FROM ....
```

Let us know how it works out for you.
For any further clarifications don't hesitate ask.

Ted.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But I'm more stuck up to check data for a particular TYP. Example, for TYP 7, TRG is Low, Neutral, Neutral. If any one was High, need to set status High only where flag=1 for that TYP and so on. So here for TYP7, Status needs to set Neutral where Flag=1 though it's TRG is Low.

Comment: Add TYP in the logic of each case statement as required. Formulate you  logic for every case you want to catch and I think is easy to follow the example I gave you.